# What evidence of US involvement in the terrorist attack in Istanbul was provided by Turkey?

Tags: united-states, turkey

As writen in [this article](https://caliber.az/en/post/122693/) Turkey rejects US condolences for Istanbul terror attack. In context of this statement:

> Turkish Interior Minister Suleyman Soylu said that Türkiye had found
> out where the attack in Istanbul was coordinated from, adding that the
> country does not accept US condolences in connection with the
> explosion.

Posibly [this article](https://www.dailysabah.com/turkey/istanbul/turkiye-slams-us-condolences-over-istanbul-terrorist-attack) describes it even beter:

> Interior Minister Süleyman Soylu said Türkiye will not accept the
> condolences issued by the United States over Sunday's terrorist attack
> that claimed six lives on Istanbul's Istiklal Street on Sunday. His
> remarks on Monday followed statements by Turkish officials hitting out
> at those who support terrorist groups, including the PKK and its
> Syrian wing YPG, the culprit in Sunday's attack. Ankara in the past
> has accused the U.S. of supplying weapons and training to the
> terrorist group in northern Syria.

So which evidence Turkey have for US involvement?

Comment: I don't know what you're reading into this.  I read it as "We know where the attack was coordinated from"  combined with "if the terrorist had not been detained, he would have fled to Greece"  to mean that the Interior minister is suggesting **Greek** involvement in the attack, not US involvement.  But Greece is an ally of the USA.

Comment: @James K Turkey is also an ally of the USA. So why they blaming USA if it seemed to be Grece?

Comment: Well that's what I mean.  I don't read this as an implied blame of the USA, but blaming Greece.  Yes, Turkey is an ally of Greece, but technically Turkey is an ally of Greece too... so much for being "allied".  But why do you think this is "blaming USA" and not "Blaming Greece".

Comment: @James K Hope the other sorce showing it beter. Turkey blaming USA to suport terrorists.

Comment: @JamesK I think it is not too far-fetched to read "not accepting condolences" as at least an indirect blame. Drawing a line from YPG to US also gives the same impression.

Comment: I just don't see any claim of involvement by the USA. I'm pretty sure that absolutely no evidence of US involvement has been presented.  It's just "This was carried out by that group that you found useful to work with in Syria".  It is a leap to go from that to thinking that this is a clear accusation of *involvement*.

Comment: I just  watched [TV news](https://www.tagesschau.de/multimedia/sendung/ts-54217.html) where Soylu was giving comments at the site of the attack. I can't understand Turkish myself, but he **was** cited as blaming the US for their "complicity", and to have said: "We know in which way the terror organization has been coordinated, and the perpetrator is who has provided YPG and PKK with information" (at 8:40).

Comment: [CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/11/14/world/istanbul-turkey-attack-suspect-syria-intl/index.html) has another quote from that statement: “Our alliance with a country Whose Senate sends funds to this mentality that provides funds for Kobani and other terror areas and aims to disrupt the peace in Turkey should be questioned. That much is clear.”

Comment: Rather unclear what you mean by "US involvement". Involvement with the YPG is well publicized by the US.

Comment: @Fizz Since Turkey rejects US condolences, there must be some kind of involvement by US.

Comment: Voting not to close - It's a simple question asking what evidence Turkey has to blame US for some terrorist incident. This can be answered factually - either Turkey has shared the evidence publicly or it hasn't.

Answer (score 8):

Turkey has a fairly long tradition of blaming foreign countries that harbor Turkish dissidents or separatists for facilitating acts of terrorism.

(BTW, the coverage by [Hurriyet](https://www.hurriyetdailynews.com/suspect-arrested-in-deadly-istanbul-bombing-minister-says-178493), English edition cites Soylu the interior minister which does *not* mention the US - but then Soylu did blame the US later on)

This is even the case when foreign countries **do** designate subgroups of those Turkish groups as terrorist entities.

This has been the case in the past with [Gulen and the US](https://www.reuters.com/article/turkey-security-usa-int-idUSKBN2A41NF).  It also has been at the center point of wrangling with Sweden and Finland to allow them to join NATO.

And with the US, they've worked quite a bit Kurdish forces in Iraq and Syria.

We may yet see evidence come out, or not, *of involvement of US-based Turkish expats* with this PKK/YPG attack.  For now, it's a bit early for the Turkish spokesman to be saying this, unless they've managed an immediate breakthrough with the **terrorists** they've arrested.  In that case, if they had real info, why stick to innuendos?

This is at least one bit of reporting that's coming out:

[Türkiye Rejects US Condolences over Blast | Asharq AL-awsat](https://english.aawsat.com/home/article/3986281/t%C3%BCrkiye-rejects-us-condolences-over-blast)

> Türkiye has been infuriated by *US support for Syrian Kurdish groups*.
>
> The Turkish official pointed the finger at Syria-based Kurdish YPG group as the people behind the bombing attack, claiming that **“the terror plot came from Ayn al-Arab”** – the district in northern Syria where the predominantly Kurdish city of Kobani is located.

And this is what [Reuters says about YPG](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/what-is-syrian-kurdish-ypg-2022-11-14/):

> The **YPG**, or the People's Protection Units, emerged as a powerful armed group during the Syrian civil war, which began in 2011. It established a foothold in the north as Syrian government forces withdrew to put down the uprising against President Bashar al-Assad elsewhere. It is affiliated to the main Syrian Kurdish faction, the Democratic Union Party (PYD), and has a female counterpart, the YPJ.
>
> The **YPG**'s influence expanded as it allied with the U.S.-led coalition against Islamic State, becoming the spearhead of a broader group, the Syrian Democratic Forces (**SDF**), which played a key role defeating the jihadists across Syria.
>
> As Islamic State retreated, the area of SDF control grew, and now accounts for around one quarter of Syria, including oil fields and several mostly Arab areas.
>
> The U.S.-led coalition says it continues to support the **SDF**.
>
> The YPG's influence expanded as it allied with the U.S.-led coalition against Islamic State, becoming the spearhead of a broader group, the Syrian Democratic Forces (SDF), which played a key role defeating the jihadists across Syria.
>
> Turkey views the **PYD and YPG** as indistinguishable from the Kurdistan Workers’ Party (**PKK**), which launched an insurgency in Turkey for Kurdish political and cultural rights in 1984.
>
> The **PKK** is designated a terrorist organization by Turkey, the **United States and the European Union**.
>
> Western states, including Turkey's NATO allies, do not view the **YPG** as a terrorist group. U.S. support for the SDF has been a source of tension with Turkey for years.

And [wikipedia entry about **PKK**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurdistan_Workers%27_Party#Designation_as_a_terrorist_group):

> The PKK has been designated as a Foreign Terrorist Organization by the US State Department since 1997.[210] In 2016, US Vice-president Joe Biden called the PKK a terrorist group "plain and simple" and compared it to the Islamic State.[211] In 2018, the United States also offered a $12 million reward for information on three PKK leaders.[212]

But, hey, this is not a court of law, but a court of public opinion.  And Turkey is in an unusually strong bargaining position at this moment because of the Russo-Ukraine war and the Sweden Finland NATO accession process.

Turkey's democracy has been somewhat imperfect since Erdogan took over and is harsh towards to a lot dissidents, minorities and separatists, **some of which do carry out terrorists acts**.  On the other hand, Western countries sometimes either collaborate with affiliated groups and provides political refugee status to others.  In Turkey's view, anyone who disagrees with their own lists of terrorists supports terrorism.

While repression has been harsher since Erdogan, this problem predates it.  And Kurd-related West-Turkey tensions have been increased by heavy involvement of Kurdish armed groups in defeating ISIS in Syria and Iraq.  Or in stabilizing (alternatively "largely separating from") parts of Iraq after the 2003 US invasion, if you want to go back that far.

And, yes, sometimes Turkish/Kurdish groups do belong on the list of terrorist entities and they get added by Western countries, though not early as Turkey would like.

"One man's terrorist is another's freedom fighter", as the saying goes.

FWIW, [PKK denies being involved](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/nov/14/pkk-denies-role-in-istanbul-bomb-attack-that-killed-six). So does [YPG](https://sdf-press.com/en/2022/11/statement-by-the-ypg-regarding-the-false-turkish-accusations/). That might be true, it might be false.  Or it might be a splinter group (we've seen that with IRA and ETA splinter groups in N. Ireland and Spain).

**Maybe this question would have been benefited from letting the facts come out a bit more.  Turkey is, understandably, angry at being targeted once again by terrorists.  Doesn't mean their claims are true.  Or untrue - in the sense that the West may need to revisit once again which Kurdish groups they are willing to back or not.**

[PKK conflict visual explainer @ Crisis Group](https://www.crisisgroup.org/content/turkeys-pkk-conflict-visual-explainer)

Comment: "Maybe this question would have been benefited from letting the facts come out a bit more." Which facts are mising, would add them to improve my question.

Comment: It's not a question of *currently known facts* missing in your question.  It is a problem that this just happened yesterday and it will take a bit of time for more information to be gathered.  Was the perp working on behalf of the YPG, a splinter thereof or as a lone wolf, but facilitated by her training from them?  Will the West revisit acceptance of YPG?  So evidence will necessarily take a time to show up.  I started writing more of a refutal, before backing it out to a "we don't know yet, but here's some background".

Comment: Re the Hürriyet article: [my understanding](https://taz.de/Terroranschlag-in-Istanbul/!5892138/) is that Soylu appeared two times: at a press conference in the morning, presenting investigation results, and again around midday at the crime scene. The quote seems to be from his first statements.

Comment: @ccprog yes, amended my citation to reflect that.

Comment: Would it be possible to slow down on the edits? It is averaging about 1 edit every 8 minutes right now.

Comment: The fact that the U.S. supports any Kurdish groups in any way, when Turkey sees them a traitors and terrorists because of the insurgency in Turkey is a long standing point of tension between Turkey and the U.S. and Turkey is reiterating this point having found an opportunity, however slight, to do so.

Answer (score 0):

About the same as for [this](https://www.files.ethz.ch/isn/193475/370_Lin.pdf):

> Turkey appears to have a double standard when it comes to terrorism. On 21 August [2015], Turkey accused BBC of
> supporting terrorists after airing a report on why Kurdish and Yazidi women join PKK to fight ISIS. At the same
> time, Turkey is supporting other countries’ designated terrorist groups: Muslim Brotherhood, Hamas, ETIM/TIP,
> Al Nusra, and other Al Qaeda affiliates that are listed by China, Russia, US/EU, Israel, Egypt and other Arab Gulf
> states, among others.  Going beyond airing a documentary, Ankara has provided material support for these
> groups, which provoked Israel to lodge a formal complaint to NATO [...]
>
> The paragraph in question appears to be BBC merely stating the obvious. “The PKK is considered a terrorist
> organization by the Turkish authorities and several Western states, but it is now a key player in the battle
> against the jihadist group Islamic State.”
> However, Ankara condemned this as some form of glorification and support for terrorism, and the foreign
> ministry statement warned BBC “This publication violates the U.N. and Council of Europe resolutions in this
> field. Promoting and glorifying terrorism is a crime.”

US support for YPG is about as public as that. And for Turkey YPG = PKK as amply documented with quotes in another answer.

I trust Anadolu's [version](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/turkiye/pkk-terrorists-in-syria-ordered-deadly-bomb-attack-in-istanbul-admits-perpetrator/2737512) a bit more than TASS', in this context:

> In her police interrogation, the suspect said she was trained as a special intelligence officer by the PKK/PYD/YPG terrorist group and she entered Türkiye illegally through Syria’s Afrin.
>
> The terrorist admitted that she had carried out the bomb attack at around 4.20 p.m. (1320GMT) on Sunday, taking the action order from the headquarters of the PKK/PYD/YPG terrorist organization in Kobani, Syria.

Ibid for [Yenişafak](https://www.yenisafak.com/en/news/footage-shows-arrival-of-terrorist-at-istanbul-bombing-scene-3655555):

> The police said Albashir has confessed that she was trained by the YPG/PKK terror group as an intelligence operative and entered Türkiye illegally from Afrin, Syria.

And [AP](https://apnews.com/article/turkey-istanbul-kurdish-bombing-ypg-terrorism-27f61eef35fbb05289d3b507331efd59):

> Albashir and a man named as Bilal el-Hacmaus were intelligence operatives of the YPG, a Syrian Kurdish militia group, and its political branch, the PYD. Turkey regards the YPG as the Syrian arm of the outlawed Kurdistan Workers Party, or PKK, which has waged a decades-long insurgency within Turkey. According to the indictment, the two suspects were given special training by the YPG/PYD and sent to Turkey along with explosives, where they traveled to Istanbul with the help of a network established by the organization. El-Hacmaus managed to flee the country. Arrest warrants have also been issued for several PKK and YPG leaders with regards to the case, including PKK leader Cemil Bayik. It is not known whether he is in Turkey, Syria or Iraq.

It's possible that Turkey decided to downplay whether those specific people had received any training by US instructors, but it's also quite possible TASS just made that up.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question:**
>
> What evidence of US involvement in the terrorist attack in Istanbul was provided by Turkey?

**Short Answer**

None, the quotes were not about the US instigating the Ankara bombings but from Turkey's perspective protecting those that did.

In 2022 Turkey's capital Ankara was hit by a series of bombings.  **[Oct 1](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/ankara-blast-echoes-past-attacks-turkey-2023-10-01/)**, **[Nov 13](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/liveblog/2022/11/13/live-news-deadly-explosion-hits-istanbuls-busy-istiklal-street)**,   After the first one.  It appears the United States which occupies Northern Syria and controls the airspace there was hesitant to permit Ankara reprisals because of the humanitarian crisis which occurred in 2019.

Oct 2019. **[Turkey’s Military Operation Has Displaced Thousands of Civilians, Worsened Syria’s Dire Humanitarian Crisis, Top Official Warns Security Council](https://press.un.org/en/2019/sc13994.doc.htm)**

After the second bombing on Oct 14th 2022 the Turkish interior minister made his comments.  Turkey rejects US niceties and says they know who is responsible, aka, you're protecting them.  A few Days later air reprisals did take place but on a more limited manor than the 2019 Turkish incursion into Northern Syria.

**Answer**

1. Oct 1, 2022 the Ankara bombing occurs. According to Turkish officials there was a woman sitting in the area of the bombing for 40 minutes, who left shortly prior to the explosion.  Turkey tracked her down and arrested her.  She was Syrian and had entered Turkey from the Northern Syrian boarder crossing.  Ankora says she was trained by the Kurds.

   see. **[What we know about who is behind the Istanbul explosion](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2022/11/14/what-we-know-about-whos-behind-the-istanbul-explosion-explainer)**
2. The United States occupies Northern Syria (only 2500 troops, but backed by significant air presence)  and is allied with Kurdish fighters there,  Not the PKK which Washington Brussels and Ankara all recognize as a terrorist organization.  The Kurdish territory has long been an area of contention between Washington and Ankara however.

3. Nov 13 Ankara get's hit again this time killing 6.
4. Nov 14 **[the Ankara Interior Minister makes his statement](https://caliber.az/en/post/122693)**.  rejecting US condolences and exclaiming they know who is responsible.
5. Afterwards the Ankara Bombing Syria bombed several sites in Northern Syria flying through U.S. controlled airspace.  With U.S. signaling it's opposition to further raids.

- Nov 24, 2022  **[Turkish air attacks on Syria threaten US personnel: Pentagon](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2022/11/24/pentagon-turkish-air-attacks-on-syria-threaten-us-personnel)**
- Nov 29, 2022 **[U.S.-backed force in Syria wants 'stronger' U.S. warning for Turkey](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/us-backed-force-syria-wants-stronger-us-warning-turkey-2022-11-29/)**

3. A year later, In 2023 Turkey moves to hit more targets in Syria,  The US intercedes shooting down Turkish drones citing U.S. troop safety.

   - 10/18/2023  **[U.S. military shoots down Turkish drones in Syria.](https://www.politico.com/news/2023/10/18/u-s-military-attempted-drone-attack-iraq-00122205)**